# C program, switch statement, prints default along with choice

Tags: c

This is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=1;
    switch(a)
    {
        case 1:
            printf("Case A");
            default:    printf("Default");
    }
}
```

Output:
Case A Default

Why is it printing even the Default case?

Comment: you forgot to `break`... no break, so you "fall through" to the next statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no break statement after `case 1` therefore control goes to execute `default` statement.

```
switch(a)
{
    case 1:  printf("Case A");
             break;
    default: printf("Default");
}
```

Comment: `int a=1;
     switch(a)
     {
      case a:
       printf("Case A"); // Why does this line gives an error?
       default:
        printf("Default");
     }
    }`

Comment: There should be a constant expression in `case` label. `a` is a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have not added the break statement for `case1`.

```
case 1:
    printf("Case A");
    break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try these:

```
switch(a)
{
    case 1:  printf("Case A");
             break;
    default: printf("Default");
}
```

It works in the following way: switch evaluates expression and checks if it is equivalent to 1; if it is, it executes printf("Case A");  until it finds the break statement. When it finds this break statement, the program jumps to the end of the entire switch statement (the closing brace).
Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/control/

Answer (score 0):

As the others have mentioned you have forgotten to put in a break statement.
The break statement is what stops the other cases from being used.

```
int a=1;
switch(a)
{
    case 1:  printf("Case A");
             break;
    default: printf("Default Case");
}
```

That being said sometimes it can be useful. If you want two cases the be run in a switch leaving out the break is how you will accomplish this:

```
switch(a)
    {
        case 1:  printf("Case A");
        case 2:  printf("Case B");
                 break;
        default: printf("Default Case");
    }
```

In this example, 1 produces "Case ACaseB" whereas 2 produces just "Case B".